# PHP Mail function issue - change sender e-mail depending on form data

Tags: php, forms, email, iis

I have an issue regarding the mail function on PHP on some forms that I have written. The problem is with the sender e-mail address. I'm using IIS7 as my web server, I have the forms written in HTML being submitted to the server via PHP. When configuring smtp on IIS as per:

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above

it states that I need to configure the sender e-mail address in the php.ini file. But I need to have this changed with each submission depending on the form content (one of the field on the form is senders e-mail).

Is there any way of doing this?? Is there another way of configuring the php.ini file?? If not can someone suggest another way of doing this??
I'm quiet new to this and slightly confused to say the least so any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create mail envelope as you like, incl. sender's email address. PHP settings got nothing with it really. I suggest you to take a look at PHPMailer (or any more advanced lib) to avoid headache with built-in `mail()`

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcin, I'll look in to that now

Comment: Hi Marcin, I was wondering if you have used phpmailer in the past? I'm having trouble withthe installation as per; https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, I've added the files: class.phpmailer.php, class.smtp.php and the autoloader to the php folder on the server. When I try to load a simple php script which includes require autoloader, I get an internal 500 error. Have I got the files in the right location??